# Entity framework - ObjectQuery return int property and assign it to variable

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, objectquery

I need to get UserCarId(int) from this query and assign to int type variable.

```
 int UserCarId;


 Entities ctx = new Entities();
                var query = from enq in ctx.UserCars.Include("aspnet_Users")
                            where enq.aspnet_Users.UserId == currentUserId
                            select enq.UserCarId ;
                UserCarId = query;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get a single record use the [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method

```
UserCarId = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

In the case of `int` the default value is 0, so if no record is found then 0 will be returned.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
I am getting this than

Comment: The message states that you are calling FirstOrDefault on a List<List<T>>, I would verify the type of UserCarId.  Additionally, you don't need the Include statement on your query.  That may be causing your problem.